# error: wx/setup.h: No such file or directory wxWidgets on CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, c, codeblocks, wxwidgets, mingw32

I have started to create an application via codeblocks using wxWidgets-3.0.2
but when I finish creating my interface, it cannot be run

#### Error log:

> C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include/wx/platform.h:183:22: error: wx/setup.h: No such file or directory
>
> C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include/wx/chkconf.h:88:9: error: #error "wxUSE_ANY must be defined, please read comment near the top of this file."
>
> C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include/wx/chkconf.h:96:9: error: #error "wxUSE_COMPILER_TLS must be defined, please read comment near the top of this file."
>
> C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include/wx/chkconf.h:104:9: error: #error "wxUSE_CONSOLE_EVENTLOOP must be defined, please read comment near the top of this file."
>
> C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include/wx/chkconf.h:112:9: error: #error "wxUSE_DYNLIB_CLASS must be defined, please read comment near the top of this file."

[image: Screenshot log]

I think that's because the following cmd command does not work on the cmd prompt:

```
mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc MONOLITHIC=1 SHARED=1 UNICODE=1 BUILD=release
```

Comment: Saying that "a command does not work" provides no details allowing to diagnose the problem.

Comment: C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2\build\msw>mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc MONOLITHIC=1 SHARED=1
UNICODE=1 BUILD=release
if not exist gcc_mswudll mkdir gcc_mswudll
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, -c "if not exist gcc_mswudll mkdir gcc_mswudl
l", ...) failed.
make (e=2): Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.
mingw32-make: [gcc_mswudll] Error 2 (ignored)
if not exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll mkdir ..\..\lib\gcc_dll
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, -c "if not exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll mkdir ..\.
.\lib\gcc_dll", ...) failed.
make (e=2): Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.
mingw32-make: *** [..\..\lib\gcc_dll] Error 2

Comment: Have you tried searching the web for [this problem](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Compiling_wxWidgets_with_MinGW#CreateProcess.2C_The_system_cannot_find_the_file_specified.)?

Comment: yes, I think that there is no gcc_dll on -> lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to build the libraries yourself, you can download prebuilt binaries from https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/releases

Comment: I would say it would be better as he is trying to build it, and it is the reccommended method as well